# Ubuntu experiences an internal error every time I log in (Going on for a few months now, not sure why)

Tags: nautilus, crash, 17.04

I built a PC and installed Ubuntu 16 on it. Every time I log in I get the same internal error.

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 17.04 has experienced an internal error
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/nautilus
ProblemType: Crash
```

I recently updated to the new Ubuntu 17.04 but I am still experiencing the same error. I don't know too much about this stuff, but I was wondering if anyone might know what is wrong?

I have tried to use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But no luck.

Thanks in advance!

crash reports:
total 12M
-rw-r----- 1 alkhalifas whoopsie 2.6M Apr 19 18:57 _usr_lib_gnome-terminal_gnome-terminal-server.1000.crash

-rw-r--r-- 1 alkhalifas whoopsie    0 Apr 19 18:57 _usr_lib_gnome-terminal_gnome-terminal-server.1000.upload

-rw------- 1 whoopsie   whoopsie    0 Apr 19 18:57 _usr_lib_gnome-terminal_gnome-terminal-server.1000.uploaded

-rw-r----- 1 alkhalifas whoopsie 8.4M Apr 23 20:42 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash

-rw-r--r-- 1 alkhalifas whoopsie    0 Apr 23 20:46 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.upload

-rw------- 1 whoopsie   whoopsie    0 Apr 23 20:46 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.uploaded
~

[image: Screen Shot of the error]

Comment: Could you please do this?  Boot into recovery mode by holding shift while booting, selecting advanced options, and choosing the latest kernel recovery mode.  Drop down to a shell, and type `cd /var/crash && ls > /home/[UserName]/file.txt`. Then type `reboot`.  upon boot, put the contents of `file.txt` from your home folder into your question

Comment: Hi there! Recovery mode did not generate what you asked for, so I did it in the regular mode instead. See above

Comment: Try deleting all of the items in that folder except `.lock`.  Then reboot and see if the error is still there.

Comment: Im afraid it did not help. Let me explain a little more about this problem: Whether I get that error or not, I experience a few weird things anytime I boot the PC up after turning it off (not suspending it, just restarting it). Everything in the system lags severely. If I open any window, the window usually crashes or takes forever to load. The only way to counter this is to click suspend and wait for the system to turn off, and then move the mouse to get it back on again. Once I log in, everything is fantastic. No idea why.

Comment: Sometimes, it's just haunted.  Consult a spiritual advisor, admit your guilt in all matters to a competent therapist or priest, make amends to those you have wronged, and reboot.  Should work then.

Comment: I have this same problem :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem ("internal error ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/nautilus
ProblemType: Crash") switching Skype off at startup applications did the trick. 2 seconds effort. (restart of course if you want to verify, or else wait till the next start up). Start up skype manually if needed. If you dont need it, best don't have it running.

any inexplicable error in any OS, it pays to check whether you got Skype running at startup. Skype is responsible for many seemingly unrelated technical issues.